# Xamarin.iOS counterpart of `FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken` method in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm working on a *Xamarin.Forms* app with push notification capability (using *Firebase*).

To get the token for Android I've used:

```cs
public async Task<string> GetTokenAsync()
{
    var t = await FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken();
    return t.ToString();
}
```

To get the token for iOS I've used:

```cs
public Task<string> GetTokenAsync() => Task.FromResult(Messaging.SharedInstance.FcmToken);
```

---

### Issue

`Messaging.SharedInstance.FcmToken` will return `null` if there is no token available and doesn't initiate requesting a token.

### Question

What is the equivalent to `FirebaseMessaging.Instance.GetToken()` method in *Xamarin.iOS*?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make `AppDelegate` implment `IMessagingDelegate` .

   ```
   public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate , IMessagingDelegate
   ```
2. Set `Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate` as `this` .

   ```
   Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;
   ```
3. Get token from `DidReceiveRegistrationToken` method .

   ```
   [Export("messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:")]
   public void DidReceiveRegistrationToken(Messaging messaging, string fcmToken)
   {
       Console.WriteLine($"DEBUG: Firebase registration token: {fcmToken}");
   }
   ```

Refer to

https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/issues/418.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3f4e61ad-fcd7-444f-9e8a-2ac50bfffa92/fcm-on-ios-messagingsharedinstancefcmtoken-empty-when-app-first-installsruns?forum=xamaringeneral.

Comment: Does this method run every time the app starts? In case the app couldn't store the token properly.

Comment: Yes ,the method is triggered when the FCM SDK retrieves a new or existing token during initial app launch and whenever the token is updated or invalidated , please refer to https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client .  What we need to do is that store it locally , you can use [NSUserDefaults](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/user-defaults) .